# Typescript possible code paths vs. typing loophole?

Tags: typescript, fall-through

Given the code

```
class X {a:string = "a"}
class Y {b:number = 1}

// does not compile
function what(v: X|Y) {
  if (v instanceof X) {
    return "its an X";
  }
  if (v instanceof Y) {
    return "its a Y";
  }
  //missing return
}
```

the typescript compiler says:

```
error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.
```

and rightly so, since due to structural typing I could call `what` as

```
let v = {b:1}
what(v)
```

since then `v` is structurally compatible with `Y`. Now I change `what` to be

```
function what(v: X|Y) {
  if ("a" in v) {
    return "its an X";
  }
  if ("b" in v) {
    return "its a Y";
  }
  // missing return
}
```

and still get the compile error.

I wonder whether the compiler just cannot derive that one of the `if` branches will be taken, or whether there is a loophole that still allows me to pass in a compatible object that does not match any of the two `if` branches.

Comment: Hmm..not sure I follow. During runtime all (type-) bets are off and anything can be passed as an argument to `what`. So given this I guess the compiler needs to make sure all paths are covered.

Comment: My hope was that the compiler can make this watertight --- at least under the assumption that we do not mix with arbitrary Javascript code. But maybe the latter always has to be assumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17358) in TypeScript.  You, reasonably, expect that [exhaustiveness checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking) will make the compiler realize that the code after the last `if` statement is unreachable.  But this doesn't happen, and it doesn't look like they are planning to address that anytime soon.

Let's see what we can do about it ourselves. 
In the following code:

```
class X { a: string = "a" }
class Y { b: number = 1 }

// does not compile
function what(v: X | Y): string {
  if (v instanceof X) {
    return "its an X";
  }
  v // Y
  if (v instanceof Y) {
    return "its a Y";
  }
  v // never
}
```

the compiler does in fact narrow the type of `v` as you pass over those `return` statements... it complains, but not because it thinks `v` might still be an `X` or a `Y` when you fall off the bottom of the function.  It complains because it analyzes code paths in isolation from the narrowing of `v`, so it sees a code path which implicitly returns `undefined` at the end.  The only way to fix this is to make sure there's a `return` or `throw` in all code paths.

Note again that `v` is first narrowed to `Y` and then to `never`.   One way you can fix the error is to take advantage of the narrowing to `Y`, and do a `return` there instead of a second `if` test:

```
function what(v: X | Y): string {
  if (v instanceof X) {
    return "its an X";
  }
  v // Y
  return "its a Y";
}
```

Now there's no error. If you trust your `instanceof X` check, this is probably the way to go.  The other standard way to go here is to use an exhaustiveness checking helper function `assertNever()`:

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
  throw new Error("OH NOES!!");
}
```

The `assertNever()` function throws an error if you call it, so it returns `never`.  But it requires its parameter to be of type `never`, so calling it should be a compiler error unless the code is unreachable:

```
function what(v: X | Y): string {
  if (v instanceof X) {
    return "its an X";
  }
  v // Y
  if (v instanceof Y) {
    return "its a Y";
  }
  v // never
  return assertNever(v);
}
```

Now `what()` is known to return `string | never` instead of `string | undefined`.  And `string | never` is just `string`.  And you can see how it functions as an exhaustiveness check, since it throws an error if you don't narrow `v` to `never`:

```
function oops(v: X | Y): string {
  if (v instanceof X) {
    return "its an X";
  }
  return assertNever(v); // error, v is Y, not never
}
```

Okay, hope those help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know a different version working with interfaces and tagged union. And this version compile correctly with all code path returning a value.

```
interface IX {kind: "a"; a: string }
interface IY {kind: "b"; b: number }

function what2(v: IX|IY): string {
    switch (v.kind) { 
        case "a":
         return "its an X";
         case "b":
         return "its an Y";
    }
}

var r1 = what2({kind: "a", a: "hello"});
var r2 = what2({kind: "b", b: 33});
```